# How does translators work in Objetify - Gae

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

While I was trying to fix an error in my app, I read something about Translators (com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate), it looked interesting but I couldn't find much about them, Someone can explain them to me very briefly? or tell me where I can find documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: so this doesnt help? https://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/translate/TranslatorRegistry.html

Comment: Ouch, that document is ancient! You can get current javadocs here: http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relevant documentation is in the javadoc comments for `Translators`, `TranslatorFactory`, and `Translator`:

http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify

But you're best going straight to the source code. There's no "printed documentation" for this stuff, but it's not overly complicated and there are lots of example translators.